# I am trying to install moodle 3.8 on my ubuntu server. I can not admin user

Tags: installation, moodle

I am trying to install moodle 3.8 on my ubuntu server. I can not admin user. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHd6W.png)
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a static files problem with your installation. The image shows that the Moodle theme lacks the CSS part.

You need to fill the email and the password fields, which are empty in the image.

Please, check your webserver configuration to see if you're setting it as intended :
https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Apache

Answer (score 0):

In order to install Moodle, you need to create an admin user. That's all that screen is prompting for. You'll need to fill in the empty fields as it prompts you to install. You cannot install without creating an admin user.